# Using strcat to create word using elemental symbols

Tags: c, strcat

I have a programming assignment where I need to use elemental symbols to construct a word, and I can only use string functions strcopy, strdup, and strcat. Here's the code I have so far...

```
char* elementsBuildWord(const int symbols[], int nbSymbols){

    char tempBuild[MAX_GENERATED_WORD_LENGTH] = {0}; // array for built word
    int i, y; // keeps count in for loop
    char* tempElement; // elemental symbol retrieved before strcat

    printf("\n");

    printf("nbSymbols = %d\n", nbSymbols);

    for (i = 0; i < nbSymbols; i++) printf("%d\n", symbols[i]);

    for (i = 1; i <= nbSymbols; i++) {
        y = symbols[i];
        tempElement = getElementSymbol(y);
        if (tempElement != NULL) {
            strcat(tempBuild, tempElement);
            printf("element #%d - %s\n", y, tempElement);
        }
    }

    free(tempElement);

    return strdup(tempBuild);
}
```

The printf statements are only there to check my progress. The array symbols is a list of the atomic numbers (the correct ones needed to spell the word) and the nbSymbols is the number of atomic numbers needed to build the word. What's happening is that the word builds perfectly, but every word gets an extra "H" (#1 for Hydrogen) at the end, and the last word passed to it causes the program to crash. MAX_GENERATED_WORD_LENGTH is a global variable. Does anything look off in my code?

One of the words that is passed to the function is the word nintendo. symbols[5] = {28, 7, 52, 60, 8}, MAX_GENERATED_WORD_LENGTH = 512. getElementSymbol is defined as follows...

```
char* getElementSymbol(int s) {

    if ((s <= 0) || (s >= MAX_NB_ELEMENTS)) 
        return NULL;
    else 
        return elementsSymbols[s];
}
```

MAX_NB_ELEMENTS = 119, and elementsSymbols[] is created from the text file, which contains each element's name.

As of now, the loop continues until it has iterated through all possible combinations of H and every other element, then moves on to combining element #2 with every possible combination, and continues until every possible combination has been made and printed.

Comment: A little more info, please.  Can you post a sample of the output from the `printf`? Also, am I correctly understanding that most words work, but one particular word causes a crash?  If so, what is that word? And just to ask for everything all at once, a sample of the `symbols[]` array, the definition of `MAX_GENERATED_WORD_LENGTH`, and either a description of, or code from, the `getElementSymbol()` function would all be helpful in diagnosing this problem.

Comment: There is no string function "strcopy()".  I think you mean "strcpy()".  But STRONG SUGGESTION: please familiarize yourself with your compiler's debugger.  It will help *immensely* in general ... and should lead you directly to the cause of this particular problem.  Learning to use a debugger is time very, very well spent. IMHO...

Comment: Just updated my original post with more info. I'm pretty new when it comes to programming. I'm using Code::Blocks with the GNU GCC Compiler. Any tips when it comes to familiarizing myself with the debugger? Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anything look off in my code?

I see two things that I highly question. Please note this is the best answer you can get without providing more input (look at the comments to your post, what are your `printf` results? what words crash the program? what does `getElementSymbol` do?)

First this line:

```
for (i = 0; i <= nbSymbols; i++) {
```

You describe `nbSymbols` as the number of symbols needed to build the word. Well in that case your loop should be `i < nbSymbols` not `<=`. If you really mean `<=` and you started the count at 0 then your description should be "one less than the number of symbols needed"

The fact that you (seemingly) are exceeding the bounds means that you could be going out of the bounds on `symbols[i]` leading to undefined behavior, including crashes or extra H's.

The second thing that bothers me is:

```
    tempElement = getElementSymbol(y);
    strcat(tempBuild, tempElement);
```

You did not provide any memory to `tempElement`, it's just a pointer. So that means it's either potentially pointing to something out of scope (a local being returned from `getElementSymbol`) or you could have a memory leak as you're constantly overwriting the dynamic memory returned from this function... can't say for sure without seeing the other function, but it's highly suspicious.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I added what happens to the bottom of my original question if I change the <= to <, and I also updated the function code to provide memory to tempElement. I don't have a very strong grasp of pointers, so hopefully I did what I needed to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the main issue is this line

```
for (i = 0; i <= nbSymbols; i++) {
```

If `nbSymbols` is 3 the loop will count 0,1,2,3.  That's not what you want. The canonical C `for` loop that iterates through `N` items is

```
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
```

so the `<=` should be a simple `<`.  That explains both the extra hydrogen and the crash.  When you got an extra hydrogen, you were just getting lucky that there was a `1` after the end of the array.

In the case where you crash, the problem is that `getElementSymbol` returns `NULL` but the `elementsBuildWord` doesn't bother to check for a `NULL` value.

Another observation. The `getElementSymbol` function uses `strdup` to create a copy of the string in the `elementsSymbols` array.  That's ok, but at some point the program needs to `free` that string.  Technically, it's not necessary to use `strdup` there since the `elementsSymbols` array will persist after the function returns.  Therefore, you are allowed to

```
return elementSymbol[s];
```

without creating a duplicate.

Having said that, I should mention that you absolutely, positively have to use `strdup` in the `elementsBuildWord` function.  The reason is that the local variable `tempBuild` is **not** going to persist after that function returns.  So you're doing it right in `elementsBuildWord`.

---

This line was correct and should not have been changed

```
    char* tempElement; // elemental symbol retrieved before strcat
```

---

The following line receives the duplicated string from the `getElementSymbol` function.

```
    ptrTempElem = getElementSymbol(y);
```

Therefore, at some point the program needs to call `free( ptrTempElem );`

This line also receives a duplicated string from the `getElementSymbol` function, but has no way to free it, so it's just bad.

```
    printf("element #%d - %s\n", y, getElementSymbol(y));
```

You can avoid the whole problem by changing the `getElementSymbol` function to this

```
char* getElementSymbol(int s) 
{
    if ((s <= 0) || (s >= MAX_NB_ELEMENTS)) 
        return NULL;
    else 
        return elementsSymbols[s];
}
```

There's really no need for `strdup` in the `getElementSymbol` function, since the `elementSymbols` array will persist beyond the end of the function, and the calling function doesn't attempt to modify the returned string.  If the calling function did want to modify the returned string, then the calling function should make the duplicate.  In your program as it stands, there is no need to make a duplicate of that string.

Comment: I changed the for loop in the original post, but I'm getting a whole new problem now that I added to the bottom. Concerning using free, would I just use free(elementsSymbols)? If I do that, do I first need to assign strdup to another variable so the information isn't lost? I'm a little confused about how it works.

Comment: @xfriendsonfirex I've added some stuff to my answer. You changed the loop, but also made a bad change.  In addition, I've added some comments about `strdup` and `free`

Comment: @xfriendsonfirex You must have changed something else in the program to get all those H's.  For future reference, it's best to make one change at a time, and observe the effects before proceeding. Also, when debugging, it's a good idea to make a backup copy of the source code so that you can hack away at the program, and then go back to the original once you figure things out.  In this case, you need to get back to where you were 14 hours ago, and then just make the change to the loop, before proceeding with the other stuff that people here are talking about.

Comment: I promise you, the only change I made that summoned the strange Hs is that for loop. I've definitely made other changes since then, but I can add that = back in and get the results I was getting 14 hours ago. It doesn't make any sense to me. I'll apply more of your suggestions when I can get back to it.

Comment: Makes no sense to me either. Changing `<=` to `<` just means that you go through the loop one less time.  It has no effect on what happens during the first time through the loop.  I suggest printing the function inputs `printf("%d\n", nbSymbols); for(i=0;i<nbSymbols;i++) printf("%d\n",symbols[i]);`

Comment: Okay, hopefully I didn't miss anything in your suggestions when updating. Thanks again for the time you're taking to help me work this out. The loop is still running through every combination of two elements. nbSymbols is always 2, and the symbols[i] are the two atomic numbers of every combination.